# Microsoft Word tables cross-hairs

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to print out some cards in MS Word using the labels feature. I'm printing 4 to an (A5) page.

I'd like to print faint cross-hairs on the page so that when it comes to guillotining them, I can simply cut them along whether crosshairs are... Is there any way to do this in MS Word 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean (I am using Word 2007)?

- Click the Labels button
- Select 'Full page of the same label'
- Click 'New document'
- Ctrl+A to select the entire table
- Click Table tools -> Design tab
- Set borders to 'Inside borders'